# How to identify tokens with single quotes by using LT(1)

Tags: antlr

I am trying to parse the following text:

```
ss1111 22'2'2 '3333' 4444 /end
```

Using the following part of an ANTLR grammar:

```
({notend = LT(1);}~END)* end:END;
END : "/end";
```

I am facing the problem **expecting ''', found '\n'**
This problem is caused because `LT(1)` is not able to identify single quotes as a token.

Can any one tell me how to handle this so that `22'2'2` and `'3333'` is also identified as tokens by ANTLR.

Comment: I edited your post to improve formatting. Can you clarify which version of ANTLR you are using? The syntax in your grammar fragment is not valid for ANTLR 3 or ANTLR 4.

Comment: I am compiling the grammar by org.antlr_2.7.6 and running with the ANTLR 3.2 <br> Actual grammar looks like <br> ifdataskip throws Exception{Token notend = null;}: ({notend = LT(1);}~END)* end:END;<br>
END : "/end";